# Is there a way for connect zidoo android tv box to android studio?

Tags: android, iot, tvbox

I have a **Zidoo** android box. So i need to build and run my android app over that android box and detect crashes. But i don't have a any cable for it. I want to know any solution for it.(Zidoo device have only two USB ports only)

Comment: is there a an one who knows any solutions for it it let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: you can try to use ADB-over-wifi

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko for that, before use need to connect device at least once my android studio.without that port not enable.

Comment: ok, then other way - you can use one of many crash reporting tools to get the crash logs without connecting the device

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko but i can't get system errors by using crash reporter.That is a problem.

Comment: what you mean by system errors?